# Bazel query on every kind but source files, ie inverted kind search

Tags: bazel, bazel-query

I was running a bazel `deps` query with an output configured as `--output label_kind` and found a ton of source file hits. Is there a mechanism for excluding source files from the results, some kind of inverse search retaining every kind but the source types? I'm imagining something perhaps like

```
bazel query "kind( ! source , deps(...))"
```

I did a quick value counts tabulation on the `label_kinds` utilized in one application and found the bulk of the deps were just source files.

```
> bazel query "deps(//my_package/my_subpackage:my_target_app)" --output rankmin | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr

8634 source
  20 cc_library
  11 filegroup
   3 config_setting
   3 cc_binary
   3 alias
   1 sh_binary
   1 py_binary
   1 package
   1 genrule
   1 bind
```

There was actually a bunch of other custom in-house rules and what not so I can't do an explicit union of kinds since there may be additions to the repo that I'd have to keep up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit verbose, but you can do something like this (split on multiple lines for readability):

```py
bazel query 'deps(//my_package/my_subpackage:my_target_app)
             except kind("source file", deps(//my_package/my_subpackage:my_target_app))'
             --output rankmin
```

The query functions `deps()` and `kind()` return sets of targets, so here we're pretty much subtracting from the full set of dependencies the set containing dependencies of type *"source file"*.